# Running a JavaScript file in Meteor JS environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, heroku

How can I run a JavaScript file on the server side in meteor JS environment ?

**Some context to what I am trying to do:**
I want to insert a document into the mongo database in an automated way. (I know how to insert documents in meteor but that is event driven like clicking a button etc...). I am using Heroku to deploy my app and I want to insert some data using the Heroku scheduler at a specified interval.

Heroku scheduler can run a file (eg: node hello.js) at a specified interval. Should I be writing a file in nodejs to what I am trying to achieve or is there a way to do in the meteor framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying [percolate:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) - a cron system for Meteor that will also allow you to scale and sync the cron with multiple servers as you grow.

Comment: my question is about trying to run a javascript file in the meteor framework.

Comment: Yes, hence why I suggested a meteor package that deals with running code at certain intervals.